# How can find what is included in the @containment annotation?

Tags: rascal

How can find what is included in the @containment annotation? I can not find that in the documentation online, that refers only to grammar-spec and nothing more? I'm talking about trying to obtain information/facts from the M3 model..

As an example:
scheme=="java+variable" or some other condition is used in a comprehesion to filter, how do you know what can be used to find certain thing??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not complete, but these pages are relevant:

- http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/m3.html#/Rascal/Libraries/analysis/m3/Core/Core.html
- http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Libraries/lang/java/m3/m3.html

I would also have a look at the code in these files:

- https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/Core.rsc
- https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/AST.rsc

They can be found in the rascal navigator view in Eclipse as well. In particular the core file contains all to know about the relations and locations in the java m3 model.